# He had done nothing about supper,___? hadn't he or didn't he

Tags: british-english, tag-questions

> He had done nothing about supper,___?

Should it finish with *hadn't he* or *didn't he*?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The correct ending would be "*had he*".

> He had done nothing about supper, had he?